# Python Webpage Scraping of HTML Tag

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, html-table

I am new to python and trying to scrape a table from a webpage, but none of the values for the columns are being pulled in. Here is an example of the td tags for a single tr.

```html
<td class="Column" style="width:200px;"><span id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_Name">email</span></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_1" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl00_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl00$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_276" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl01_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl01$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_2" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl02_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl02$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_5" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl03_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl03$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_3" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl04_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl04$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_7" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl05_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl05$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_4" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl06_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl06$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_6" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl07_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl07$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
```

```
   soup = bs(html_content, 'html.parser')


   table_rows = soup.find_all('tr')

   for tr in table_rows:
      td=tr.find_all('td')
      value = td.find('value')
      row =[i.value for i in td]
    print(row)
```

I have tried a number of different ways but can't figure out how to pull the information fro the values tag.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to get `value` attribute from `<td>` tag. Instead of `<td>`, select `<input>` tags.

This script will select all `<input>` tags inside `<td>` and will print content of `data` and `value` attributes:

```
html_content = '''<td class="Column" style="width:200px;"><span id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_Name">email</span></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_1" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl00_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl00$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_276" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl01_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl01$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_2" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl02_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl02$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_5" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl03_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl03$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_3" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl04_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl04$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_7" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl05_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl05$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_4" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl06_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl06$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_6" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl07_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl07$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(html_content, 'html.parser')

for i in soup.select('td input'):
    print(i['data'], i['value'])
```

Prints:

```
38_4255_1 0.3500
38_4255_276 0.3500
38_4255_2 0.3500
38_4255_5 0.3500
38_4255_3 0.3500
38_4255_7 0.3500
38_4255_4 0.3500
38_4255_6 0.3500
```

EDIT: To select name of column:

```
html_content = '''<tr><td class="Column" style="width:200px;"><span id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_Name">email</span></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_1" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl00_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl00$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_276" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl01_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl01$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_2" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl02_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl02$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_5" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl03_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl03$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_3" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl04_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl04$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_7" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl05_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl05$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_4" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl06_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl06$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td>
<td class="Column" style="width:125px"><input class="sf d" data="38_4255_6" id="ctl00_MainContent_Value_ctl1543_Row_SF_ctl07_SFV" maxlength="10" name="ctl00$MainContent$Value$ctl1543$Row$SF$ctl07$SFV" type="text" value="0.3500"/></td></tr>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

soup = bs(html_content, 'html.parser')

for row in soup.select('tr'):
    header = row.select_one('td').text
    print(header)
    for i in row.select('input'):
        print(i['data'], i['value'])
```

Prints:

```
email
38_4255_1 0.3500
38_4255_276 0.3500
38_4255_2 0.3500
38_4255_5 0.3500
38_4255_3 0.3500
38_4255_7 0.3500
38_4255_4 0.3500
38_4255_6 0.3500
```